# $Resource global variable is not available in Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, static-resources

I try to build a lightning component embedded in Lightning Experience. My org is **Summer 16 Dev Org**.

The component is in a Account record page.

When using follows, it compiles successfully.

```
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.leaflet + '/leaflet.css'}" 
              scripts="{!$Resource.leaflet + '/leaflet.js'}" 
              afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.jsLoaded}" />
```

But I got an error on loading:

> Uncaught Action failed: ltng$require$controller$init [TypeError: d.get is not a function]

However, using as follows is OK.

```
<ltng:require styles="/resource/leaflet/leaflet.css" 
              scripts="/resource/leaflet/leaflet.js" 
              afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.jsLoaded}" />
```

**Complete code:**

AccountMap.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
   <ltng:require styles="/resource/leaflet/leaflet.css" 
              scripts="/resource/leaflet/leaflet.js" 
              afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.jsLoaded}" />
   <div aura:id="map"></div>
</aura:component>
```

AccountMapController.js

```
({
    jsLoaded : function(component, event, helper) {
        alert('ff');
    }
})
```

Comment: Is the test environment same version as production ? I believe $resource + ... Is only available as of Summer 16 ?

Comment: Are you within a managed package and does your component include a controller?

Comment: @MarkKeats What effect would that have? I was having a similar issue and the answer to both of your questions, in my case, would be yes.

Comment: @CloudHugger My org is Summer 16 Dev Org.

Comment: @Mark Keats Mine is not in a managed package and there is no namespace in the org. Also this component has no server-side controller, but has a client-side controller.

Comment: @JunKe Looks like this was an Known Issue and it has been fixed https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000183G6QAI

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you fall into one of the following:

1) Your code is within a managed package, in which case you would need to alter the reference to include the namespace prefix. If your namespace was 'mynamespace' then you would need the following:

```
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.mynamespace__leaflet + '/leaflet.css'}" 
              scripts="{!$Resource.mynamespace__leaflet + '/leaflet.js'}" 
              afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.jsLoaded}" />
```

2) Your code is within a component that does not have a client-side controller. In this case your component will be rendered server-side and the $Resource value provider does not work there.

> First, $Resource isn’t available until the Lightning Component
>   framework is loaded on the client. Some very simple components that
>   are composed of only markup can be rendered server-side, where
>   $Resource isn’t available. To avoid this, when you create a new app,
>   stub out a client-side controller to force components to be rendered
>   on the client.

Documentation at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_resource_value_provider.htm